# Relational DB which can do inserts at billions of rows with multiple indexed columns?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, index, sqlite, rdbms

I am looking for advice on a database to potentially replace SQLite for my application.

To briefly describe my DB requirements:

- needs to support billions of rows and the most queried table has multiple indexed columns (this is currently causing slow imports with SQLite at 15m rows)
- inserts done manually weekly, but should be done quickly i.e not having to go to sleep and wake up before i can query the DB with the freshly imported 100k-1m rows
- almost no update queries

The only problem i have so far is the speed of importing new data sets into my DB, which i only need to do infrequently and manually. It has gotten very slow if not impossible to import data with the current amount of records (15 million) due to the indexing. This leaves me two options for SQLIte inserts:

1. Spread the data across thousands of SQLite tables - added complexity and i believe this would all need to be custom coded in my app
2. Drop indexes -> insert new data -> re-create indexes - also quite slow

Could PostgreSQL or another relational DB offer fast inserts with multiple indexed columns up to 100 million + rows?

Comment: Any DBMS can do that. The question is how _fast_ do you need to insert those 100 million rows. Where does the data come from? Flat files that need to be imported or from your application? pgloader can load flat files using multiple threads which might help. Can the data be partitioned? Then you could load into multiple partitions simultaneously. Only of course, if your hardware is fast enought (SSDs, CPUs)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the data would be read from files, processed with python then inserted via the python connector for the DBMS i choose. I wouldn't be inserting 100m rows at once but rather anywhere from 100k-1m rows into the table which already contains 100m rows.

Comment: Do you need the Python step? Loading a million rows through `copy` will be the most efficient way to do that. How do you do the inserts from Python? Are you doing single row inserts (slow) potentially with auto-commit enabled? You should insert all rows in a single transaction, ideally using multi-row inserts (at least in Postgres)